# Add column with number of ratings per user, pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working with a book rating dataset of the form

```
userID | ISBN | Rating
23413    1232     2.5
12321    2311     3.2
23413    2532     1.7
23413    7853     3.8
```

Now I need to add a fourth column that contains the number of ratings each user has in the entire dataset:

```
userID | ISBN | Rating | Ratings_per_user
23413    1232     2.5         3
12321    2311     3.2         1
23413    2532     1.7         3 
23413    7853     3.8         3
```

I have tried:

```
df_new['Ratings_per_user'] = df_new['userID'].value_counts()
```

but I get an error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

and the entire new column is filled with `NaN`.

Comment: `df_new['Ratings_per_user']=df_new.groupby('userID')['userID'].transform('count')`

Comment: this works, mind making it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df_new['Ratings_per_user']=df_new.groupby('userID')['userID'].transform('count')
```

---

```
   userID  ISBN  rating  Ratings_per_user
0   23413  1232     2.5                 3
1   12321  2311     3.2                 1
2   23413  2532     1.7                 3
3   23413  7853     3.8                 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert result of `value_counts` into `dict` and then use `replace` to create new column with user ratings

```
x = df['userID'].value_counts().to_dict()

df['rating_per_user'] = df['userID'].replace(x)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  userID  ISBN  rating  rating_per_user                                                                                              
0   23413  1232     2.5                3                                                                                              
1   12321  2311     3.2                1                                                                                              
2   23413  2532     1.7                3                                                                                              
3   23413  7853     3.8                3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map`:

```
df['Rating per user'] = df['userID'].map(df.groupby('userID')['Rating'].count())
print(df)

   userID  ISBN  Rating  Rating per user
0   23413  1232     2.5                3
1   12321  2311     3.2                1
2   23413  2532     1.7                3
3   23413  7853     3.8                3
```